# Can i stream data to a custom_post_type?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, database

I want to create a plugin which records user's location every 3 seconds. Is it a good idea to use a custom post type field to store that data, if so, can you demonstrate how I can use it with PHP stream?

Or should I use a custom table and stream the data to that table?

Comment: You could store it in the _usermeta table so that it's related to a user, but it sounds like it could be saving a lot of information. Depending on the number of users and amount of information/how important it is, it might be worth looking at storing it in an external nosql database like mongo.

Comment: In addition, as a plugin, it should probably use its own table so that you can easily wipe all data on an uninstall.

Comment: what do you think of the php websockets is it a good option for my above requirements.